# How to perform operations on changed lines in Emacs before-save?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to add a before-save-hook where I can do some operations for just the lines that have changed since the last save. For e.g., remove trailing whitespace, check indentation, etc.. I don't want to do this for an entire file, and I am aware that there are individual options for each of these(just to remove trailing whitespace for all changed lines, etc..), but I'd like something generic so that I can add more stuff to it. I imagine there is something where I can either get the list of line numbers changed, or a get-first-changed-line(), get-next-changed-line() type of functions.

Comment: Maybe you could use `ediff-mode` in some sort of way.

Comment: Which operation-specific packages are you referring to? You could maybe re-use part of their implementation. `ws-trim.el` for example relies on a post-command hook to remove whitespace on changed lines. In any case, if your operation is not computationally heavy and can be applied line by line, I think it would be easier to run it after each line modification rather than on the whole buffer in a before-save hook.

Answer (score 3):

### use highlight-changes-mode machinery

You could use `highlight-changes-mode` and then iterate over the text property `hilit-chg` set by it using `next-single-property-change`.

E.g.,

```
(with-current-buffer "my-buffer-name"
  (let ((beg (point-min)) end)
    (while (setq end (next-single-property-change beg 'hilit-chg))
      (setq beg (next-single-property-change end 'hilit-chg))
      (message "[[%s]]" (buffer-substring-no-properties end beg)))))
```

will produce the following:

```
[[
these are my changes

]]
[[ and here]]
[[
here are more changes
]]
```

in the `*Messages*` buffer (and in the echo area).

#### full implementation example

[ws-butler](https://github.com/lewang/ws-butler) uses this mechanism to trim spaces at EOL on save for modified
lines.

Comment: I was playing around with highlight-changes-mode but couldn't figure out how iterate over the text properties. Could you explain a little more? (Sorry, but this is really my first attempt at elisp :)

Comment: @VijayKotari: use function `next-single-property-change` with property `hilit-chg`.

Comment: Coincidentally, this is how I implemented a better(IMO) ws-trim mode -- ws-butler.