# adding a function to <enter> in emacs

Tags: emacs

I wanted to add (delete-trailing-whitespace) with my enter.

I can't find what  gives and hence I can't bind it to my new function.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally I don't recommend binding it to the enter key as that can happen quite often and may be slow, instead I use

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)
```

This just removes all the trailing whitespace when you save the file instead of each time you hit a key.

If you still want to bind it then see @ataylor's answer instead.

Comment: Wish I could +2 this.  It's a horrible idea.

Comment: Removing *all* trailing whitespace from a file can easily cause problems when version control (especially with multiple developers) enters the picture. Your commits will be much cleaner if, when you save a file, Emacs *isn't* making changes to lines that you hadn't edited.

Comment: @phils It would be much cleaner if there wasn't any excess whitespace and tabs to begin with :P

Comment: Absolutely, but that's a different problem. If other developers are putting trailing whitespace into files *now*, they will continue to do so *later*, even if you are periodically eradicating it. Unfortunately you can't change their habits by editing your own .emacs.

Comment: @phils That's true, although the OP was calling delete-trailing-whitespace anyway this solution just amortizes the cost.

Comment: For sure, and it's certainly a huge improvement on the original idea; but personally I think the likes of `ws-trim` or `ws-butler` are really the way to go on this issue.

Comment: @phils That's true, I guess the OP really meant to remove trailing whitespace on the line that they hit enter on. In which case you can just bind a delete-trailing-whitespace on the region between beginning and end of current line.

Answer (score 3):

How about just removing whitespace from the lines you are pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> on?

```
(defun delete-whitespace-on-this-line-then-newline ()
  "before doing a newline, remove any trailing whitespace on this line"
  (interactive)
  (save-match-data
    (save-excursion
      (beginning-of-line)
      (when (re-search-forward "\\s-+$" (line-end-position) t)
        (replace-match ""))))
  (newline))
```

It's not as good an answer as [Jesus Ramos's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14615866/6148), but it's kind of what you're asking for.

Comment: It's possible that's what he meant it looks like he chose the brute force approach to it though.

Comment: yeah, thats exactly what I had thought but I chose a nuclear missile to kill the mosquitoes in my room :)

Answer (score 2):

Keys have to be bound to commands, so first define a command that does what you want:

```
(defun delete-trailing-whitespace-newline ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-trailing-whitespace)
  (newline))
```

The defun needs an interactive form at the top level to be a command.  Then bind the key to the command:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'delete-trailing-whitespace-newline)
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this answer, and its comments:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14164500/324105

I use `ws-trim` to automatically remove trailing whitespace *only* from lines which I edit (which is a more robust solution to what I believe you are wanting to achieve with your key binding for <kbd>enter</kbd>).

event_jr also mentions `ws-butler`, which does something similar, but only removes the trailing whitespace when you save (still only from lines which you have edited).